# 2D plot of 3 variables

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I have three dataset xx, yy, tau, for which I would like to realize a 2D plot.

Hence, I produce the following code, which return a contour plot by `tricontourf`. In particular at each value of `tau(i)`, a given value of `xx(i)`, `yy(i)` is associated.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,8))
ax.set_xlabel('$\lambda$', fontsize=22)
ax.set_ylabel('$l_0$', fontsize = 22)

tcf = ax.tricontourf(xx, yy, tau, levels = 100)
cbar = fig.colorbar(tcf)
cbar.set_label(' \u03C4$_k$', fontsize =22)
plt.show()
```

All good for now. But how can I plot the value of tau simply as points/ dashed lines within this contour plot?

Comment: With `ax.scatter(xx, yy, marker='o')` you could indicate the positions. Maybe use the `s` parameter to let the marker's size indicate tau? (It's hard to say without knowing how tau looks like.)  If there are only few values, a text could be placed instead of a dot. Could you add some test data, similar to the data for your use case?

Comment: They look like this: (0.01, 6.0) -2.52 \\
(0.01, 8.66) 2.72 \\
(0.01, 11.33) 1.99 \\
(xx, yy) tau. Each of the dataset has 100 points, and the values of tau somehow link to a linear behavior, which I would like to show.